# Add translation to a script option line inside JS as a variable Prestasip

Tags: javascript, prestashop, smarty

i want to translate day in prestashop tpl (1.7.6.9)
but doesent work, i have this script in a tpl. when i try to translate in prestashop always in French. do you have a solution ?

```
<script>
var carrier_store_delivery_id = "{$carrier_store_delivery_id}";
var current_post_code = "{$post_code}";
var current_address1 = "{$address1}";

var current_city = "{$city}";
var current_country = "{$country}";
var optionDefaultLabel = "{l s="Please select a day" mod='moduledelivery'}";
var optionRangeDefaultLabel = "{l s="Please select a time slot" mod='moduledelivery'}";

var dayList = [
    "{l s='Lundi' mod='moduledelivery'}";
    "{l s='Mardi' mod='moduledelivery'}";
    "{l s='Mercredi' mod='moduledelivery'}";
    "{l s='Jeudi' mod='moduledelivery'}";
    "{l s='Vendredi' mod='moduledelivery'}";
    "{l s='Samedi' mod='moduledelivery'}";
    "{l s='Dimanche' mod='moduledelivery'}";
];

var cancel_label = "{l s='Annuler' mod='moduledelivery'}";
var choose_label = "{l s='Choisir' mod='moduledelivery'}";
var store_addresses = [];
{foreach from=$coordinates item=element}
    store_addresses.push({$element|@json_encode nofilter});
{/foreach}
```

Comment: This should work as I used the same approach in some developed modules. 
Of course your module name should be "moduledelivery" and you should have properly translated the strings trough the legacy Prestashop translation system.
Also - If you are developing locally make sure to have cache disabled and "Force recompile" in smarty cache options.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop default modules are the best guide.

blockcart module => blockcart.tpl :

```
{strip}
{addJsDefL name=customizationIdMessage}{l s='Customization #' mod='blockcart' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=removingLinkText}{l s='remove this product from my cart' mod='blockcart' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=freeShippingTranslation}{l s='Free shipping!' mod='blockcart' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=freeProductTranslation}{l s='Free!' mod='blockcart' js=1} {/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=delete_txt}{l s='Delete' mod='blockcart' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=toBeDetermined}{l s='To be determined' mod='blockcart' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{/strip}
```